# Can we send multiple emails from survey monkey to same emailid

Tags: surveymonkey

I am using an Email collector for sending survey invitations. I am directly adding the recipients in the below way while sending the survey invitations. However, I have a situation to send multiple invitations to the recipient with same emailID. How can we send multiple invitations in that case? If I include multiple emailID's in the same request, survey monkey mark it as "duplicate" and only one email will be sent.

Can we send multiple emails from survey monkey to same emailid?

```
POST /collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/recipients/bulk
{
    "contacts": [{
        "email": "user1@example.com",
        "first_name": "User 1",
        "last_name": "Testing" 
    },{
        "email": "user2@example.com",
        "first_name": "User 2",
        "last_name": "Testing" 
    },{
        "email": "user1@example.com",
        "first_name": "User 1",
        "last_name": "Testing" 
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send to the same email twice, as you said, it will show up as a duplicate and only send once.

I'm not really sure the use case for sending two messages to the same email at the exact same time, but if you want to send to the same email again, you need to create a new message on that collector and add the recipient to the new message.